# Метод Print в С# не могу понять почему метод работает криво

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void GetStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Firt Name of student");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Last Name of student");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter birthday of student");
        string birthday = Console.ReadLine();

    }   
    static void PrintStudentDetails(string first,string last, string birthday1)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday1);

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetStudentInformation();
        Console.WriteLine();

        //string first = "1";
        //string last = "2";
        //string birthday1 = "3";

        PrintStudentDetails(first,last,birthday1);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

} 
// выводит мне чушь, подскажите как описать метод PrintStudentDetails
// что бы выводил мне значения которые вводит пользователь о студенте 
// в методе GetStudentInformation
```

Comment: Нужна ваша помощь в обуздании сей вещи)

Comment: А под чушью что подразумевается? Да и код не рабочий, так явно все переменные не обьявлены

Comment: После ввода данных вы их тут же теряете, так исполнение выходит за их пределы видимости

Comment: если переменный инициализирую то выводит их, если нет то на выводе консоль падает после ввода данных о студенте. как правильно передать параметры что бы вывело мне данные о студенте методом PrintStudentDetails

Comment: Всё дело в области видимости переменных. Почитайте в литературе это место еще раз

Comment: @StanislavKovalenko: А вы знаете, что такое локальная переменная?

Comment: да я понмаю что это. мне нужно объявить переменную в мейне но при этом не понимаю как дергнуть то значение которое вводит пользуватель для вывода в консоль

Comment: @StanislavKovalenko: У вас из `GetStudentInformation` должна возвращаться информация, а покамест она там образуется и остаётся внутри, никому не нужная.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда у вас есть связанные переменные их обычно объединяют в одну сущность

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Birthday;
}
```

Выделяем логику работы с сущностью в отдельный класс

```
public class StudentController
{
    public Student GetInformation()
    {
        var student = new Student();

        student.FirstName = ConsoleEx.ReadLine("Enter First Name of student");
        student.LastName = ConsoleEx.ReadLine("Enter Last Name of student");
        student.Birthday = ConsoleEx.ReadLine("Enter birthday of student");

        return student;
    }   

    public void PrintDetails(Student student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{student.FirstName} {student.LastName} was born on: {student.Birthday}");   
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Похожие действия убираем в отдельный метод.

```
public static ConsoleEx
{
    public static string ReadLine(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Затем вам нужно получить объект и передать его дальше.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        var controller = new StudentController();

        var student = controller.GetInformation();

        Console.WriteLine();

        controller.PrintDetails(student);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Вернуть переменные из метода

```
public static GetInfo(out string firstName, //...
{
    firstName = ConsoleEx.ReadLine //...
    //...
}

public static void Main()
{
    string firstName;
    //...

    GetInfo(out firstName, //...

    PrintInfo(firstName, //....
}
```

Сделать их частью класса

```
public static GetInfo()
{
    FirstName = ConsoleEx.ReadLine //...
    //...
}

private static string FirstName;

public static void Main()
{
    GetInfo();

    PrintInfo();
}
```

Comment: может класс student превратить в структуру?

Comment: спасибо, все понятно. но есть маленький вопрос, к примеру мы не используем классы или структуры, если сделать это методами, как в моем примере описать получения информации о студенте в методе и описать принт метод, потом я в мейне выполняю обращение к методу. заполняю форму, как мне потом взаимодействовать с переменными что бы я мог обратиься в м\мейне к методу принт и отобразить то что ввел

Comment: Вам нужно эти переменные вернуть из метода или сделать переменные доступными для всего класса

Comment: спасибо, попробую!